# Oracle SQL Query to display the sequence begining number and ending number

Tags: sql, oracle

A table has

```
Vendor_ID Warrant_ID
1         100
1         101
1         102
1         105
2         106
2         108
2         109
2         110
2         111
2         115
3         120
3         125
```

I need to display

```
Vendor_id Warrant_seq_begin Warrant_seq_end  Gap
1         100               102               0
1         105               105               2
2         106               106               0
2         108               111               1
2         115               115               3
3         120               125               4
```

Comment: could you write why is there a difference between `1         105               105               2` row and `3         120               125               4` - according to the pattern the last row should be split into 2 rows: `3         120               120               0` and `3         120               125               4` or am I missing something ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. You are correct. It should be 2 rows. The Gap is the difference between the last sequence end and the next sequence begin.

Comment: Thanks for your review and response. Did you manage to find the solution with the help from other users ?

Answer (score 1):

This may help give some ideas to start. It gives a result without the gap:

```
SELECT vendor_id
      ,MIN(ws_begin) AS warrant_seq_begin
      ,NVL(MAX(ws_end), MIN(ws_begin)) AS warrant_seq_end
  FROM ( SELECT vendor_id
               ,CASE WHEN seq_start <> 0 THEN warrant_id ELSE NULL END AS ws_begin
               ,CASE WHEN seq_start = 0  THEN warrant_id ELSE NULL END AS ws_end
               ,SUM(seq_start) OVER(ORDER BY vendor_id, warrant_id) AS grouping

           FROM (

                  SELECT vendor_id
                        ,warrant_id
                        ,NVL(lag(warrant_id) OVER(PARTITION BY vendor_id ORDER BY warrant_id), warrant_id) AS prev_warrant_id
                        ,CASE WHEN NVL(lag(warrant_id) over(PARTITION BY vendor_id ORDER BY warrant_id), warrant_id) + 1 <> warrant_id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS seq_start
                    FROM my_table
                    ORDER BY 1, 2, 4
                 )

       )
  GROUP BY vendor_id, grouping
  ORDER BY vendor_id, grouping
```

Result:

```
VENDOR_ID   WARRANT_SEQ_BEGIN   WARRANT_SEQ_END
1   100     102
1   105     105
2   106     106
2   108     111
2   115     115
3   120     120
3   125     125
```

Probably easiest to understand if you start looking at the results of the inner most queries and work out.  The innermost query just wants to flag anytime the "sequence" is broken:

```
VENDOR_ID   WARRANT_ID  PREV_WARRANT_ID     SEQ_START
1   100     100     1
1   101     100     0
1   102     101     0
1   105     102     1
2   106     106     1
2   108     106     1
2   109     108     0
2   110     109     0
2   111     110     0
2   115     111     1
3   120     120     1
3   125     120     1
```

Next level out (middle query) sums the flags of the previous query to create groupings:

```
VENDOR_ID   WS_BEGIN    WS_END  GROUPING
1   100     (null)  1
1   (null)  101     1
1   (null)  102     1
1   105     (null)  2
2   106     (null)  3
2   108     (null)  4
2   (null)  109     4
2   (null)  110     4
2   (null)  111     4
2   115     (null)  5
3   120     (null)  6
3   125     (null)  7
```

The idea is to break it into groupings, building a sparse matrix, then compressing the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

This is using dense rank where sampled is your sample table and the query gives your desired result:-

```
select Vendor_ID,series_frm,series_to,
series_frm-nvl(lag(series_to) over 
(partition by Vendor_ID order by  series_to)+1,series_frm) gaaap
from
(
 SELECT  Vendor_ID,MIN(Warrant_ID) series_frm, MAX(Warrant_ID) series_to
 FROM    (   SELECT  Vendor_ID,Warrant_ID,
                Warrant_ID - dense_rank() OVER(ORDER BY Warrant_ID) series
        FROM   sampled
    ) tab
 GROUP BY Vendor_ID,series
)
order by 1,2;
```